# Using custom fonts on Android

Tags: java, android, fonts

I'm trying to load a custom font as follows:

```
private Paint customFont18;
customFont18 = new Paint();
customFont18.setTextSize(18);
Typeface fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "FONT.TTF"); 
customFont18.setTypeface(fontFace);
```

The getAssets fails, thows this:

```
-The method getAssets() is undefined for the type MyClass
-assetManager cannot be resolved to a variable
```

What is my problem? I've seen several examples like this but none works in my case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, it must be activity to work?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be an activity in order to work. Where in the project is your FONT.TTF file located?

Comment: the font is located in the "assets" folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getAssets()` is a method of Context. If your class is not an activity, you'll need to pass a context into it and then call `getAssets()` on that.

```
public myClass(Context myContext) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(myContext.getAssets(), "FONT.TTF");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing like this:

```
Typeface fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FONT.TTF");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple [EasyFonts](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2044) third party library to set variety of custom font to your `TextView`. By using this library you should not have to worry about downloading and adding fonts into the assets/fonts folder. Also about Typeface object creation.

Simply:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
myTextView.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoThin(this));
```

This library also provides variety of font faces.